# Can't add 'otherMails' with Graph-Tester

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to add another email address to a User.

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain.de
```

Body:

```
{ 
    "givenName":"Meier",
    "surname":"Meeier",
    "otherMails":["emaissssl@domain.de"] 
}
```

Response:  `Success - Statuscode 204`

The result is `givenName` changed to `Meier`, `surname` changed to `Meeier`, but the email doesn't get added to `otherMails[]`.

A related question is, can I change the primary address of the User?

Edit: I get the same behavior, if i also include the current address:

```
{
  "givenName": "Meier",
  "surname": "Meeier",
  "otherMails": ["user@domain.de", "emaissssl@domain.de"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need spesific permissions in AAD to update `otherMails`. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

> Updating another user's *businessPhones*, *mobilePhone*, or *otherMails* property is only allowed on users who are non-administrators or assigned one of the following roles: *Directory Readers*, *Guest Inviter*, *Message Center Reader*, and *Reports Reader*. For more details, see *Helpdesk (Password) Administrator* in [Azure AD available roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#available-roles). This is the case for apps granted either the `User.ReadWrite.All` or `Directory.ReadWrite.All` delegated or application permissions.

The wording is a little poor but basically, if the User record you are updating is an Administrator or assigned any of the mentioned roles (*Directory Readers*, *Guest Inviter*, *Message Center Reader*, or *Reports Reader*), it will ignore the change request.

As for changing the primary email address, that isn't possible. The primary email address is automatically constructed based on the `mailNickname` and the default domain for the tenant (`mailNickname@default.dom`).

Comment: Thanks for your help! The User has no roles assigned and he isn't an Administrator. Regarding primary email address: I can change it via Exchange Admin Center and also in Office 365 Admin Center, so i thought i can do it also via Graph API.